# Don't allow direct calls to Microservices. Only allow through Zuul API Gateway

Tags: spring-security, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have created multiple microservices like movie-catalog-service, movie-rating-service and movie-info-service.and also created "ZULL API Gateway".

All the request are allowed from the Zuul API Gateway. I want to stop the users from direct access the URL of individual services.

Is there a way to stop users from directly accessing the services mentioned in A and B (only allow the ones that come through the API Gateway)